# Airflow BashOperator to return value and use in subsequent task

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use BashOperator to execute a python script with a set of arguments. The python script which is executed need to pass some value back so that the next task, which is also a BashOperator executing another python script, can use the value as process accordingly.

I am researched on xcom, but did not come across anything which can be used for returning back the value from BashOperator.

I am new to Airflow, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XComs are what you use to allow tasks to communicate with each other, either in the same DAG run or across DAG runs.

The [documentation page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) on XComs is a good place to start.

XComs are implicitly set when using the `BashOperator`. The last line of output is stored as an XCom and this can be used in any other operator.

In Operators you will find templated fields. These are documented in the Airflow documentation pages, and in the docstrings of the Operators themselves.

The `bash_command` argument to the `BashOperator` is a templated field. This means you can use XComs in this field.

An example of an output of one `BashOperator` being used as input to a second downstream `BashOperator` is:

```py
import pendulum
from textwrap import dedent
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator


@dag(start_date=pendulum.today(tz="Europe/London"))
def test_dag():
    bash_operator_0 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_0",
        bash_command=dedent(
            """
            echo "hello-world"
            """
        ),
    )

    bash_operator_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_1",
        bash_command=dedent(
            """
            echo "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0') }} from bash_operator_1"
            """
        ),
    )

    bash_operator_0 >> bash_operator_1


test_dag_failure_dag = test_dag()
```

The log output of `bash_operator_1` shows that the result of `bash_operator_0` is being used in the command of `bash_operator_1`:

```
[2022-05-26, 21:53:25 BST] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', '\necho "hello-world from bash_operator_1"']
[2022-05-26, 21:53:25 BST] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-05-26, 21:53:25 BST] {subprocess.py:92} INFO - hello-world from bash_operator_1
[2022-05-26, 21:53:25 BST] {subprocess.py:96} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2022-05-26, 21:53:25 BST] {taskinstance.py:1395} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=test_dag, task_id=bash_operator_1, execution_date=20220526T205323, start_date=20220526T205325, end_date=20220526T205325
```

Comment: it doesn't worked for me